# What's the purpose of the "merges" and "runs" tags in a Cordova plugin?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I've seen these tags used in a couple plugins from apache, but it isn't documented anywhere on what the functionality is. Here's an example taken from the Cordova File Plugin `plugin.xml`:

```
<js-module src="www/fileSystemPaths.js" name="fileSystemPaths">
    <merges target="cordova" />
    <runs/>
</js-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in Cordova docs.

**Merges** is to merge JS namespace of plugin with the one existing in Cordova.

Example :

If a `cordova.screenshot` exists, and have the method `cordova.screenshot.takePicture`. If the plugin has a `cordova.screenshot.takeVideo` it will be added there instead of making unavailable `takePicture`.

Cordova docs :

> Allowed within `js-module` element. Used to specify the namespace under window object where `module.exports` gets merged with any existing value. If any key already exists, the module's version overrides the original.

**Runs** is to don't make the plugin available on window object.

Cordova docs :

> Allowed within `js-module` element. It implies that your code should be specified with cordova.require, but not installed on the window object. This is useful when initializing the module, attaching event handlers or otherwise.

[Here is Cordova docs link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/plugin_ref/spec.html#merges)